# Control del número de usuarios que están logueados en mi sistema

Tags: c#, sql, login, usercontrol

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un procedimiento que me controla el registro de todos los usuarios que inician sesión. Lo que estoy tratando de realizar es introducir gráficamente en un campo de texto el número de usuarios que están logueados en mi sistema.

Este es mi procedimiento ejecutado:

```
  string sql3 = @"exec [gen].[sp_EBR_usuariosRegistrados] {0}"; 
     sql3 = string.Format(sql3);
     DataTable dtResultados = this.Ets.Api.Util.Db.GetDataTable(sql3).Return;       
      txtNpersonas.Text = Conversor.convertirString(dtResultados.Rows.Count.ToString());
      txtNpersonas.DataBind();
```

La verdad es que no sé como realizarlo, ya que con mi procedimiento controlo todos los usuarios logueados, pero no sé hacer para mostrar por pantalla el número de ellos que se encuentra logueado, estoy un poco perdido en este ámbito.

Comment: y no podes preguntarle al datatable cuantos registros tienen? (no recuerdo, si no es un simple count a al tabla de usuarios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he podido realizar lo que quería gracias por los comentarios. A continuación comento el código con el que ha funcionado.

```
string sql1 = @"exec [gen].[sp_EBR_usuariosRegistrados] {0}"; 
     sql1 = string.Format(sql1,this.SistemaID);
     DataTable dtresult =  this.Ets.Api.Util.Db.GetDataTable(sql1).Return;

      txtNpersonas.Text = Conversor.convertirString((dtresult.Rows.Count.ToString()));
      txtNpersonas.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes contar la cantidad de registros en el DataTable y despues estos bindearlos a un control en este caso a un label.

Ademas agrege una forma basica de imprimir los datos en el listView

Espero que te sirva, Saludos

PD: Tuve que hacer un DataTable a mano, para efectos del ejemplo.

.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="StackOverflow.test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="FORM_TEST" runat="server">
        <div>
            personas conectadas : <asp:Label ID="lblConectados" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListViewEjemplo">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="nombre" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NOMBRE") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var _data = PoblarConDataPRueba();

            ListViewEjemplo.DataSource = _data.DefaultView;
            this.ListViewEjemplo.DataBind();

            lblConectados.Text = _data.Rows.Count.ToString();
            lblConectados.DataBind();
        }

        private DataTable PoblarConDataPRueba()
        {
            DataTable _dataTable = new DataTable();
            _dataTable.Clear();
            _dataTable.Columns.Add("NOMBRE");

            DataRow _row = _dataTable.NewRow();
            _row["NOMBRE"] = "PEDRITO";
            _dataTable.Rows.Add(_row);

            DataRow _row2 = _dataTable.NewRow();
            _row2["NOMBRE"] = "JUANITO";
            _dataTable.Rows.Add(_row2);

            DataRow _row3 = _dataTable.NewRow();
            _row3["NOMBRE"] = "MARTINCITO";
            _dataTable.Rows.Add(_row3);

            return _dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

--RESULTADO--

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He modificado el código con lo que me facilitaste pero con mi procedimiento tengo un error de instancia que no se que puede ser. He adjuntado la foto del error en mi pregunta.